# Fredrick Taylor Inspired Optimization for Shovel Loads

Tags: optimization, econometrics, misspecification

**Premise**

In Taylor's original [Principles of Scientific Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Principles_of_Scientific_Management), the optimal weight of a single shovel load was calculated (roughly 21 pounds). This had some interesting implications: short of this optimal load, you are simply wasting energy; conversely, exceeding the optimal load results in rapid fatigue. Essentially it boils down to a constrained optimization problem: find the maximum amount a man can shovel given limited chemical energy resources (aka worker stamina). This was all carried out over timed experiments, which he called "time studies."

**Question**

With this premise in mind, I would like to devise an optimization technique for determining how heavy a load a man using a shovel should carry for the general case. Supposing that some men are more effete, sickly or otherwise different than the stock worker in the classical time studies, we would need to calculate these individual's optimal shovel loads respectively. What is the best way to achieve this?

I initially considered using something like Constrained Optimization BY Linear Approximation (COBYLA), but I do not think I will be able to paramatize "stamina" with any degree of confidence.  Currently, I'm trying to model the process in econometric fashion (least squares):

```
y(optimal load) = c + β1*age + β2*vo2max + β3*bmi + βkXk + μ
```

where Y(optimal load) is the average load of the individual. I would assume the workers would eventually find their groove on their own initiative. In other words, they would not exert themselves with shoveling too much at once or waste effort carrying too little.

The trouble with this is that workers could be performing sub-optimally on purpose (Taylor noticed this happened, workers feared that being too efficient would result in job cuts). I'm not sure how to adjust the incentives in my study to account for this danger.

I would appreciate expert advice on the model specification or about the feasibility of constrained optimization (other forms are welcome).